# Redirect and hide target URL

Tags: php, redirect, video, authorization

I want to implement a website which like Youtube, these real URLs of videos has to be hidden.

When a user comes in, and the PHP webpage will authenticate the user, and redirect that user to the real URL of the video. The problem is how can I redirect URL and hide its real video URL, or other ways to prevent the real URL of videos exposed?

Comment: The 'real url'? What do you mean by that? The url the user sees is as real as it gets. You surely have to pass an ID of some sort, as your site needs to know which video it has to serve, doesn't it?

Comment: @giorgio yes, in general, our site know all the paths of videos. Users have to pay will be able to watch the videos of our website, so we don't want the urls of videos captured by Wireshark software then bypass our billing mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got your point, but are you looking for something like this?

```
$video_url = $user_is_authenticated ? $video_url : $authentication_url."?returnUrl=".$video_url;
echo "<a href='$video_url'>Video Title</a>";
```

This way, if the user is authenticated, you send him the real video URL, otherwise the login page would be seen instead.

If you don't want users to see the URL you can use [session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) during authentication.

Answer (score 0):

URL bar can be hidden using JavaScript in InternetExplorer using `window.open` method.

And that will work only in InternetExplorer. And remaining browsers dont allow you to hide address bar, as per security issues.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the video location, I guess. Make a script to feed your video to your front.

```
feed.php?video=id
```

This will read your video file based on the video id and return it with propper headers to your frontend player.

Comment: Whether this approach can avoid a video path is detected by Wireshark software?

Comment: Wireshark only analyses networks. That would be a server side script that will server the video as a stream based on an id. Wireshark can't analyze remote php scripts. Or am i wrong? :)

Comment: NO, I'm just afraid that the player will connect to video server, and the video path will be captured during the player connects to that video server. However, I will try the method. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!